# width not displaying on the site

Tags: css

I am trying to fix the width of the menu on [this](http://www.inspuratesystems.com/bankalhabib/) website. When I use Firebug to see the width it shows me 949.66px width of the menu but it does not show up in the css. Please guide me. Thanks.

Comment: If it wont show up, you add width in css using %

Comment: It may be already set in percents(**%**). Try resizing the browser and see if the width is the same.

Comment: width is set on container div - .menu-main... also, position of menu items is set by using negative margin, so navigation appears above parent/container div.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That css is coming from the bootstrap maybe, the navbar is using the ::before pseudo element for image, so the rest of the space of the container (excluding image) is taken by your navbar, which might not be specified in the css but it is just taking rest of the space since it is a block level element.

Answer (score 0):

`#navbar-collapse-1` is a `block` type element. So by default it's 100% width. If you want to change it, you have to set new value (what you want).